# Remmina client connect from RPI to Windows 10 Home

Tags: remote, windows, pi-3

I'm trying to start a remote desktop session from my RPi3 to my PC (*running Windows 10*) using [Remmina](http://www.remmina.org/). Windows 10 Home doesn't have the option to allow remote connections. How can I connect from my RPI to my PC running Windows 10 Home?

I couldn't find any clear examples/tutorials. I found [this](https://eltechs.com/run-teamviewer-on-raspberry-pi/) alternative for running teamviewer on my PI, but Exagear Desktop is paid software, and I prefer a free solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have Remmina installed in your RPI, and your connections are in the same **local network** the easiest solution will be to install a VNC server in your desktop.

You have several alternatives: [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/), [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/), etc. Usually the installer already open ports and let everything ready to connect. But if you have doubts here you have an article explaining [How To Remote Control Your Home Computer From Anywhere With VNC](http://www.howtogeek.com/124849/how-to-remote-control-your-home-computer-from-anywhere-with-vnc/).